# Phone book search on AWS Lambda and S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to make a serverless application in AWS Lambda for phone book searches.

What I've done:

1. Created a bucket and uploaded a CSV file to it.
2. Created a role with full access to the bucket.
3. Created a Lambda function
4. Created API Gateway with GET and POST methods

The Lambda function contains the following code:

```
import boto3
import json

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

resp = s3.select_object_content(
    Bucket='namebbacket',
    Key='sample_data.csv',
    ExpressionType='SQL',
    Expression="SELECT * FROM s3object s where s.\"Name\" = 'Jane'",
    InputSerialization = {'CSV': {"FileHeaderInfo": "Use"}, 'CompressionType': 'NONE'},
    OutputSerialization = {'CSV': {}},
)

for event in resp['Payload']:
    if 'Records' in event:
        records = event['Records']['Payload'].decode('utf-8')
        print(records)
    elif 'Stats' in event:
        statsDetails = event['Stats']['Details']
        print("Stats details bytesScanned: ")
        print(statsDetails['BytesScanned'])
        print("Stats details bytesProcessed: ")
        print(statsDetails['BytesProcessed'])
        print("Stats details bytesReturned: ")
        print(statsDetails['BytesReturned'])
```

When I access the Invoke URL, I get the following error:

```
{errorMessage = Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function', errorType = Runtime.HandlerNotFound}
```

CSV structure: Name, PhoneNumber, City, Occupation

How to solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like your handler configuration on the lambda is not correct.

Comment: As the error states: `HandlerNotFound`. You are missing the handler function. Check documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wecome to S.O.  @smac2020 links you to the right place [AWS Lambda function handler in Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html).  In short, AWS Lambda needs to know where to find your code, hence the "handler".  Though a better way to think about it might be "entry-point."

Here is a close approximation of your function, refactored for use on AWS Lambda:

```
import json
import boto3


def function_to_be_called(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    
    resp = s3.select_object_content(
        Bucket='stack-exchange',
        Key='48836509/dogs.csv',
        ExpressionType='SQL',
        Expression="SELECT * FROM s3object s where s.\"breen_name\" = 'pug'",
        InputSerialization = {'CSV': {"FileHeaderInfo": "Use"}, 'CompressionType': 'NONE'},
        OutputSerialization = {'CSV': {}},
    )
    
    for event in resp['Payload']:
        if 'Records' in event:
            records = event['Records']['Payload'].decode('utf-8')
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!'),
        'pugInfo': records
    }
```

This function produces the following result:

```
Response
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\"",
  "currentWorkdingDirectory": "/var/task",
  "currentdirlist": [
    "lambda_function.py"
  ],
  "pugInfo": "1,pug,toy\r\n"
}
```

The "entry point" for this function is in a Python file called `lambda_function.py` and the function `function_to_be_called`.  Together these are the "handler."  We can see this in the Console:

[image]

or using the API through [Boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.get_function_configuration)

```
import boto3
awslambda = boto3.client('lambda')
awslambda.get_function_configuration('s3SelectFunction')
```

Which returns:

```
{'CodeSha256': 'mFVVlakisUIIsLstQsJUpeBIeww4QhJjl7wJaXqsJ+Q=',
 'CodeSize': 565,
 'Description': '',
 'FunctionArn': 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:***********:function:s3SelectFunction',
 'FunctionName': 's3SelectFunction',
 'Handler': 'lambda_function.function_to_be_called',
 'LastModified': '2021-03-10T00:57:48.651+0000',
 'MemorySize': 128,
 'ResponseMetadata': ...
 'Version': '$LATEST'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, I figured it out, fixed the error and tried to check the functionality using your example. Everything works!

Comment: @Jack_Old, You're welcome!  Enjoy S.O. and AWS!

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this documentation topic to learn how to write a Lambda function in Python. You are missing the Handler.  See: [AWS Lambda function handler in Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html)